# does it make sense to use apache as web server for django in development mode

Tags: python, django, apache, distributed

I'm a newbie in django and have a project that involves distributed remote storage and I'm suggested to use mod x-sendfile as part of the project procedure.
In have a django app that receives a file and transforms it into N segments each to be stored on a distinct server. Those servers having a django app receiving and storing the segments.

But since mod x-sendfile works need apache and I am just in developing and trying stage this question occurred to me.

I googled a lot but found nothing in that regard.

So my question being: Is it possible to use apache as django web server during the development of django apps? Does it make sense in development mode to replace apache with django built-in web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be nothing stopping you from installing a copy of Apache on your workstation and using it for developing, and since you're working on something that depends on some of that functionality it makes perfect sense for you to use that for your development server instead of ./manage.py runserver.

Most people use Djangos built-in server because they don't need more than that for what they're trying to do - it sounds like your solution does.

Heck, since you're testing distributed you may even want to consider grabbing a virtualization tool (qemu, virtualbox, et al) so you can have a faux-distributed setup to work with (I'd suggest doing a bit of scripting to make it easy to deploy / restart them all at once though - it'll save you from having to track down issues where the code that's running is older than you thought it was).

Your development environment can be what you need it to be for what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam, I have VMWare workstation hosting my VMs for the testings.